# Find unique IDs which entries do not have a certain value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following dataset (the actual database has thousands of rows)

[image]

I want to find which unique studies do not have any "accept" value, count them, and exclude them. For the sample dataset, `boutch2000` and `earl2008` should be excluded because none of its entries yielded `accept` value. I believe Excel can do this, but I can't seem to find the right formula. How can I do this?

EDIT: Ideally, this is how the end product should look like.

[image]

I found a way using `INDEX` and `MATCH`

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$2:E2, $A$2:$A$14), 0)),"")}`

```
 with cell `E2` as the new dataframe containing unique ids and `A2:A14` 
 as the source list
```

This command produces a list of unique ids in a new dataframe. However, the command can only be executed as an array formula, which takes a long time to load. Also, I can't use VBA as I'm working in Sharepoint

I'm still working in formulating the formula to count the occurrence of `accept` and `reject` for each unique ids, though..

Comment: Yes, so in short I want to create another data frame with the list of unique ids, the number of entries accepted (based on `final` column), and the number of entries rejected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Excel 365**, you can easily generate a unique list*:

```
=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$14)
```

To count the accepted and rejected cells

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$14,E2,$B$2:$B$14,"accept")
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$14,E2,$B$2:$B$14,"reject")
```

*If you only want a unique list of IDs that definitely has at least one "accept", then

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$A$14,$B$2:$B$14="accept"))
```

**In older Excel versions** without FILTER or UNIQUE, starting in E2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$14), 0)),"")
```

for all unique IDs or for only "accept" IDs

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1, $A$2:$A$14)+($B$2:$B$14="reject"), 0)),"")
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can filter the tabel to find out the ID with "accept" value.

Then copy the ID display on screen to another cloumn, go to Data tab > Data Tools group > Remove Duplicates, get the unique IDs with"accept" value.

[image]

Then use the formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$14,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:$D$4,A$2:A$14)=0,ROW($2:$14)-1,10^4),ROW(A1)))&"","")` and drag down to find out the IDs in column A but is not included in column D. Please do not forget press Ctrl+Shift+Enter key, as it is an array formula.

[image]

But as the result have dupalicate IDs, you can copy the dtat and use the "Remove Duplicates" feature again. Or use formula `=UNIQUE(G2:G5,FALSE,FALSE)` to get the unique IDs that have "reject" value for its each entry.

[image]

Then use formula `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$14,D2,B$2:B$14,"accept")` to get the number of entries accepted (based on final column).

[image]

Use the formula `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$14,I2,B$2:B$14,"reject")` to get the number of entries rejected.

[image]